# How do I adjust my icons (imagebuttons) so that they won't zoom in?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, adobe-illustrator

Here's a link to what my home screen currently looks like:

```
https://imgur.com/a/WKZ5nHG
```

Here's a link to what I'd like it to look like (this is my IOS version!):

```
https://imgur.com/a/IfEw2Ek
```

I currently have All the correct size versions in the folder. I want The home screen to look like my iOS version. I'm wondering if this is something I fix in the code, or if it's something that I fix using sketch/illustrator. Please let me know and I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Here's what my main activity.xml file looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_learn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/learn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/learn_layer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/learn"
        android:textSize="22sp"
       />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_find_care"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/find_care_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/find_care_layer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/learn"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_talk_to_doctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/TalkToADocButton"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/talk_doc_layer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_visit_website"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/VisitWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"

        android:src="@mipmap/visit_web_layer"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `android:padding` attribute to adjust - you know what? Padding :)
e.g `android:padding="12dp"` on your ImageButton

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstood the linearLayout, you just need one nested level :

- LinearLayout

  - ImageView
  - ImageView
  - ...

Then for your issue, as padding may help, this is probably more the scaleType that trigger the actual rendering. Try fitCenter, and let me know what's is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I found the solution by using `background:` instead of `src:`.